# Freezing the scale of XYZ layers

Tags: qgis, scale, xyz-tiles

I am trying to use an xyz layer to align with some additional layers that will be overlaid.  My problem is that the imagery at a resolution closer than 1:2900 is almost a decade old, so I don't want this to be shown at all.  Once you zoom out further than 1:2900 the image was captured in 2020 and is good to be used.

Is there a way to freeze the scale so that when you zoom closer than 1:2900 the pixels will just become larger rather than the old image being loaded?

I know I have managed to do this before, I thought by clipping the xyz file but having had a look around I can't replicate my process.

The xyz file in question is [https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}](https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D) and I am using QGIS 3.16.11 (Hannover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the XYZ connection > `Edit Connection...`, then set Min./Max. Zoom levels.

ArcGIS maps have 24 zooms levels (0 to 23) according to the site where you also find [this interactive tool](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/reference/zoom-levels-and-scale/) to translate zoom levels to map scales: zoom level 17 corresponds to a scale of ca. 1:4514, zoom level 18 to 1:2257.

So you should set **zoom levels from 0 (min.) to 17 (max.)**, see:

[image]